# jquery remove appended style tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a code that appends style to the head on hover of a div, but when I hover out i want to destroy that previously appended style tag, is that possible? here is my code...

```
jQuery( "#diamonds div" ).hover(
  function() {
    jQuery(this).find('img.label').fadeTo( "fast", 0 );
    jQuery(this).find('.dj-social').delay(200).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );

    var className = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];
    jQuery('head').append('<style>.'+ className +':before {background-size:120% auto !important;}</style>');

  }, function() {
    jQuery(this).find('.dj-social').fadeTo( "fast", 0 );
    jQuery(this).find('img.label').delay(200).fadeTo( "fast", 1 );

    var className = jQuery(this).attr('class').split(' ')[1];

        // ----This is where I want to destroy the style tag i have just inserted   
        jQuery('head').remove('<style>.'+ className +':before {background-size:100% auto !important;}</style>');

  }
);
```

Heres my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XwdkC/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `Hover` Toggle:

```
$(element).hover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('yourStyle');
}, function() {
    $(this).removeClass('yourStyle');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use classes instead of amending the inline styling. That way you can utilise jQuery's `addClass()` and `removeClass()` functions.

Comment: unfortunately i have to append an inline style because the background image is applied with the css propoerty .diamond-tiesto:before which i cant target